# How to computer an Array Average

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm trying to write code that averages out an array. I keep getting a return statement error and main class missing error. Please help.

```
public class ArrayAverage {
    public static double average(double[] x){
        // declare and intialize array to hold value
        int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3 ,4, 5};

        //calculate sum of all array elements
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
        sum = sum + numbers[i];

        //calculate average value
        double average = sum / numbers.length;

        System.out.println("Average value of array elements is : " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! You omitted to say what language you are using, which prevents the right expert coming to your assistance. I guessed it is C#. Remember to tell us all the relevant details....

Comment: Doesn't every single Java (?) tutorial start with how to create a `main`?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the code entry point is always the `main` method. It has the following signature: `public static void main(String[] args)`

You must invoke your `average` method in the `main` method for the application to run.

Additionally, your `average` method declares to return a value of type `double`. However, the method has no return statement. You must either write at the end of your method `return val;` (val being whatever double value you wish to return) or have your method return type declared as `void`.

More so, your method has a parameter `x` that is of type `double[]`. When invoking your method (in the `main` method) you must pass it such an argument. Or, you can change your method signature to accept nothing (no arguments).

Now, as for the body of your method. It's not written in best practice, but functionaly it looks good, except for one thing.

> //calculate average value
>   double average = sum / numbers.length;

This will do integer division, giving you an integer answer. This means that any value after the decimal place will be truncated. To fix this, do one of two things:

1. Declare `sum` as a `double`
2. When dividing, cast `sum` or `numbers.length` as a double

   `double average = sum / (double) numbers.length;`

P.S. I can tell this is Java by your use of `System.out.println`. In the future, be sure to tag your question with Java, or whichever language your code is in.